# Starting a new terminal from within a terminal on linux using python

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

I have a script running on a terminal and if a condition is met it starts another script. The problem is it pauses the first script, I want them to run simultaneously if possible the second one should run on a new terminal that should be started within code. Im using python and Raspbian as the linux distro and I tried to open second terminal within code this way:

```
os.system('lxterminal -e '<process to ivoke>'')
```

And I got this error:

> (lxterminal:4036): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: `os.system("lxterminal -e '<process to ivoke>' &")`

Comment: @dsgdfg I still get the same error.

Comment: When you try os.system('echo $DISPLAY'), what do you get?

Comment: I got nothing so I used "export DISPLAY=:0" and when I echoed it it displayed ":0" . But I still get the same error. I even tried running xhost +localroot and even then I still got same error.